# Set time value into data frame cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to set a time value into a data frame:

```
ps = data.frame(t(rep(NA, 2)))
ps[1,1] = strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')
```

but I get the error:

```
provided 9 variables to replace 1 variables
```

since a time value is a list (?) in R it thinks I'm trying to set 9 columns, when I really just want to set the one column to that class.

What can I do to make this set properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to the result of `strptime()` being an object of class `"POSIXlt"`:

```
> ps = data.frame(t(rep(NA, 2)))
> ps[1,1] = strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, 1, value = list(sec = 0, min = 30L,  :
  provided 9 variables to replace 1 variables
> strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')
[1] "2012-03-21 10:30:00"
> class(strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S'))
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

A `"POSIXlt"` object is a list representation (hence the `lt` rather than the `ct` in the class name) of the time:

```
> foo <- strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')
> str(foo)
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2012-03-21 10:30:00"
> unclass(foo)
$sec
[1] 0

$min
[1] 30

$hour
[1] 10

$mday
[1] 21

$mon
[1] 2

$year
[1] 112

$wday
[1] 3

$yday
[1] 80

$isdst
[1] 0
```

A `"POSIXlt"` object is a list of length 9:

```
> length(unclass(foo))
[1] 9
```

hence the warning message, as the object is being stripped back to it's constituent parts/representation. You can stick the `"POSIXct"` representation in instead without generating the warning:

```
> ps[1,1] = as.POSIXct(strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S'))
> ps[1,1]
[1] 1332325800
```

but we are still loosing the class information. Still, you can go back to the `"POSIXct"` representation later using the `as.POSIXct()` function but you will need to specify the `origin` argument. See `?POSIXct` for more.

```
> class(ps[1,1])
[1] "numeric"
```

A solution is to coerce `ps$X1` to be class `"POSIXct"` *before* inserting the time:

```
> ps = data.frame(t(rep(NA, 2)))
> ps <- transform(ps, X1 = as.POSIXct(X1))
> ps[1,1] <- as.POSIXct(strptime('10:30:00', '%H:%M:%S'))
> ps
                   X1 X2
1 2012-03-21 10:30:00 NA
> str(ps)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1: POSIXct, format: "2012-03-21 10:30:00"
 $ X2: logi NA
```

No warning (as before with `as.POSIXct()`) but also the class information is retained, where before it was lost. Do read `` ?`[.data.frame` ``, especially the **Coercion** section which has some details; but my take how is that understanding the coercion in replacements like this is tricky.

Comment: Awesome, and a follow up question, I initially have the POSIXlt in a data frame that I load with read.table and a custom class/parser. Is the reason that data frame was able to hold the list because it had its class coerced to POSIXlt?

Comment: If you told `read.table()` the correct classes via the `colClasses` argument then it takes you at your word. The problem you are seing is that you are trying to stick a `"POSIXlt"` object into a vector that is class `"logical"` (that is what you get when you define `ps` in the way you did (check `X2` in the very last code example - note the `logi NA`). There is nothing wrong in holding any sort of object in a data frame (subject to the atomicity of the individual vectors) - the issue here is the coercion rules when the target and origin classes are not the same.